# How to swap ctrl+enter and ctrl+shift+enter in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In VS 2015, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> puts the cursor above the current line while <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> puts it below. I find it rather counterintuitive because the usage of the latter is more frequent yet it requires more keystroke. I wonder how can I switch them in the VS settings?

Answer (score 0):

These shortcuts map to the **Edit.LineOpenAbove** and **Edit.LineOpenBelow** commands. You can reassign them in Visual Studio keyboard options.

Comment: Just another question, can I save the settings, including my key mappings somewhere and restore them if I reinstalled VS?

Comment: Never mind, I just found that import and export option. Thanks!